# Question realted to standard field of quaternions and multiplicative group.

Tags: algebraic-groups, quaternions

Let $H$ denote the standard field of quaternions over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that it is a division ring (every non zero element has a inverse). It is a non-commutative division ring.

Let's denote its multiplicative group by $H^{*}$.

I have read that it is a $4$ dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$ - algebraic group. I am not able to write a proof.

Comment: Note that $H^\ast$ is identified to an open set in $\Bbb Q^4$

Answer (score 1):

Technically $H^*$ is not an algebraic group over $\mathbb Q$, but rather the set of rational points of an algebraic group $\mathbf H$ over $\mathbb Q$.  (An algebraic group is a type of functor from fields to groups.)

Modulo this technicality, one way is to realize $H$ in $M_4(\mathbb Q)$ (pick a basis, and associate each element of $H$ to the 4x4 matrix given by this action).  Then you can check $H^*$ is given by polynomial equations, and that it gives an algebraic group similar to the proof that GL($n$) is an algebraic group.

Comment: Kindly mention some references, I want to read more about it.

Comment: @Sri I don't know one off the top of my head, but I have some notes on quaternion algebras on my website.  I don't quite prove $H^*$ is an algebraic group, but the realization in $M_4(\mathbb Q)$ is in there, and it's clear it's given by polynomial conditions.  For instance, look at Exercise 2.1.8 for the embedding of $H$ in $M_2(\mathbb C)$, which you can put in $M_4(\mathbb R)$ or $M_4(\mathbb Q)$ by embedding $\mathbb C$ in $\mathbb R$ as in Exercise 2.1.6.

Comment: One more thing, I want to ask. When we save "4 dimensional algebraic group", I guess by dimension we mean dimension as a variety.

Comment: @Sri Yes, that's correct.